# Can I post a same document to 2 different collections in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to post the same document with same ID's to 2 different collections I tried this:

```
 db.collection("users").add({
    name: "userName",
    lastName: "userLastName"
})
.then(userDocRef => {
    userDocRef.collection("favFood").add({
        favDrink: "userDrink",
        favDessert: "userDesert",
 })

 // then post the same information to different collection
 .then(userDocRef => {
    db.collection("users__2").add({
        name: "userName",
        lastName: "userLastName"
    }).then(userDocRef => {
        userDocRef.collection("favFood").add({
            favDrink: "userDrink",
            favDessert: "userDesert",
    })
 })

});
```

and It worked Everything was the same But the ID was different is Possible to Have the same ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `add()` method you generate a new Firestore document ID, this is why the Firestore document IDs are different.

You should use the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method without specifying any path: "an automatically-generated unique ID will be used for the returned DocumentReference". Then you use this document ID as follows, since there is no problem to use the same ID in two different collections.

```
const userDocRef = db.collection('users').doc();
userDocRef
.set({
    name: 'userName',
    lastName: 'userLastName',
})
.then(() => {
    return userDocRef.collection('favFood').add({
    favDrink: 'userDrink',
    favDessert: 'userDesert',
    });
})
.then(() => {
    return db.collection('users__2').doc(userDocRef.id).set({
    name: 'userName',
    lastName: 'userLastName',
    });
})
.then(() => {
    db.collection('users__2')
    .doc(userDocRef.id)
    .collection('favFood')
    .add({
        favDrink: 'userDrink',
        favDessert: 'userDesert',
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response But it keeps on giving the "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')" Error

Comment: See the update: I was re-declaring `userDocRef` in the second `then` block.

Comment: Now its gives "TypeError: _firebase_config__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.db.collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function" Error and when I check the firebase console it created the first half but not the second

Comment: There was another error…. Updated!

Comment: Now its gives "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')" and it happens on the .then(user2DocRef => {
    return user2DocRef.collection("favFood").add({
        favDrink: "userDrink",
        favDessert: "userDesert",
    })
})

Comment: Ok, now it should be ok, see the update! Sorry I couldn't test it before.

Comment: Aww Man Thank you soo much it worked, you literally saved me I am doing a big project and I used The favFood question as a sort of Lite version of the Big question so other people can Understand

Comment: @MinenhleSolsonCele Glad I could help you! Don't forget to upvote my answer ;-)